# ubuntu 20.04 Ruby on rails devise unpermitted param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, parameters, ubuntu-20.04

I updated ubuntu from 19.10(all works well) to 20.04.
Got error **Unpermitted parameter: session** when log in.

```
Started POST "/auth/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-06-05 20:29:41 +0300
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"EMAIL", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "session"=>{"email"=>"EMAIL", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
Unpermitted parameter: session
Unpermitted parameter: session
  User Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND (BINARY email = 'EMAIL' AND provider='email')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameter: session
Unpermitted parameter: session
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (0.09ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 321 LIMIT 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 101ms (Views: 8.5ms | ActiveRecord: 4.1ms | SQL count: 5)
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Without further info it's really hard to tell, nothing changed between 19.10 and 20.04 that should have this effect. Did you change ruby versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was that the library Device used a third-party one gem Bcrypt, that was removed in version 4.2, I have version 3. Link to the problem: https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/226. Updating bcrypt to version 3.1.13 solves my problem, my version was 3.1.11 before.